# 'openssl/rsa.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am using ccavenue as the payment gateway. I am getting `"'openssl/rsa.h' file not found"` this error while running the application.

Is there any way to add openssl via cocoapods or avoid this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to import the file via writing "openssl/rsa.h" instead of <openssl/rsa.h> ?

Comment: Did you install openssl on your system? You can use Homebrew for that: `brew install openssl`

Comment: @iPeter That fill not fix the issue. Many other "not found errors are coming"

Comment: @Koen I will try this

Comment: @Koen I installed openssl, Can you tell me the next step or procedure for that ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341113/how-to-add-openssl-to-an-xcode-project

Comment: @vijeesh: that link explains how to add openssl to your Xcode project, and your error should be gone.

Comment: @Koen It worked thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have come across this sha.h not found error on a Mac/ios development, it is because Apple dropped support for openssl.(I faced this error in my macOs-mojave version)

refer to this link : https://www.anintegratedworld.com/mac-osx-fatal-error-opensslsha-h-file-not-found/

You can follow the steps below as a workaround for this issue:

1. `brew install openssl`

- This will install a folder called openssl into your /usr/local/Cellar folder (where all your other brew downloads reside).

2. `cd /usr/local/include`

- The trick though is to go into your usr/local/includes folder and create a symlink (aka folder shortcut in the windows world) to your Cellar folder.

3. `ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl`

- `ln` is used to create a link and `-s` means it is *symbolic*. Next we are saying what is the destination and the `.` (dot) indicates to create the link in the current directory.

Now when you compile the code, the warning should disappear because your compiler will search in this directory (one of many standard directories) and find the header file sha.h via the shortcut link.

You should probably run a few other commands as best practise:

4. brew doctor
5. brew update
6. brew upgrade

This will resolve issue.

Note : I faced this particular issue (openssl/rsa.h file not found) when i was trying to install 'RSclient' package in my R environment.

Comment: Why mess with the symbolic links when you can just provide a `-I` to the compiler?