# pjsua2 on ios Library not found for -lssl

Tags: ios, pjsua2

Getting pjsip user agent sample project working

I have compiled the libraries for pjsip here:

[pjsip ios](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone)

I have gotten android to work and I am trying to get the xcode project running for the user agent.  I have compiled it against openssl.  I added the user agent library and the openssl libraries to the library folder.  Once done, I have one error left that I cannot seem to solve:

Showing All Errors Only
Library not found for -lssl

**I am getting this even when I do not use or build against the openssl options**

my openssl libs are:  libcrypto.a and libssl.a once those are added, my error count goes from 111 to one.  This is my first ios project so I was wondering if I missed a step adding the references.

Answer (score 0):

has nothing to do with whether ssl is enabled.  Some of the libraries use openssl so the project needed header and library paths.  Copied the OpenSSL output I already had to the project, and it built fine

Found the answer here: Wai Ha Lee answered it.

[add open ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341113/how-to-add-openssl-to-an-xcode-project)