# Create CocoaPod with OpenSSL-Universal as Dependency

Tags: ios, swift, openssl, cocoapods, static-libraries

I'm trying to create a CocoaPod that has OpenSSL-Universal as a dependency. Whenever I go to the auto-generated `Example` subfolder and run `pod install`, I get the following error message:

> [!] The '…' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (…/Example/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libcrypto.a and …/Example/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/lib-ios/libssl.a)

This error is not there when I remove `use_frameworks!` from the `Podfile` in this directory. However, I have another project, a Swift project, which has OpenSSL-Universal as a dependency, and because it's a Swift project, `use_frameworks!` is present in its `Podfile`. And yet somehow, it manages to perform `pod install` with no issues.

I've been trying to create both Swift and Objective-C CocoaPods with the OpenSSL-Universal dependency, and yet to no avail. There are other Pods, however, such as CoreBitcoin, that do have it as a dependency, and they, too, can be included in my Swift projects with `use_frameworks!`. However, when I try to use CoreBitcoin as a dependency in my own CocoaPod instead of OpenSSL-Universal, the same error is thrown as above, also for OpenSSL-Universal.

How do I make my own CocoaPod with that dependency? What am I doing wrong? I haven't changed any other default settings except for experimenting with the presence of the `use_frameworks!` flag in the auto-generated example subdirectory.

Comment: Also be aware that OpenSSL is *not* multiarch safe out-of-the-box, so you have to take care to use it like that. I've seen a number of folks provide one, but its simply wrong. There are lots of GitHub projects that are simply wrong (including one of mine). Also see [Build Multiarch OpenSSL on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25531033/608639).