# Electron crashes with C++ addon using openssl library

Tags: c++, openssl, electron

I am trying to run with Electron a C++ addon that links to the openssl library. When the C++ code tries to access the library I get an exception: Procedure not found. I found another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38639455/electron-native-addon-failing-on-windows), but I could not manage to make it work, as the original poster said it would. I tried to link to a static compiled library from [here](http://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/), specifically libeay32MT.lib but when running under Electron it still crashes.

In bindings.gyp I have the library added like this:

```
"-l$(OPENSSL_ROOT)/lib/libeay32MT.lib"
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: `-l` requires something like `-l32MT` and a search path specified with `-L` to find that.

Comment: but it's an absolute path. shouldn't it work? I tried without the -l also. I don't get any compilation error, just runtime when I try to access stuff from the lib.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the problem: I was also linking to **node.lib** inside the **bindings.gyp**. It wasn't necessary, but I "inherited" it from the Visual Studio proj file, where the **node.lib** was mandatory in order to compile the addon for **node**.

After removing the unnecessary library link to node.lib from the bindings.gyp the electron app worked just fine.