# Compile Crypto++ library for OS X Xcode project

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, crypto++

I have downloaded Crypto++ and I am trying to build it so that I can use it in a C++ Xcode project.

I compiled using just "make" command and included `libcryptopp.a` in my c++ project of my xcode. But it is giving errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "CryptoPP::HashFilter::HashFilter(CryptoPP::HashTransformation&,
 CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation*, bool, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
 std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
 std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
 ...
```

Comment: Default make will build it with `-march=native` option, which leading to a x86_64 binary.

Comment: what should I do then? @halfelf

Comment: Why not just use Common Crypto ,it is all "C" code and has optimizations for hardware support.

Comment: @zaph - Common Crypto only works on Apple systems. Apple also abandons its libraries and frameworks on down level OS versions. I have so many unpatched Apple hardware they outnumber the patched ones. Lack of QA is yet another problem with Apple software. I recommend avoiding Apple libraries at all costs.

Comment: Depending on the implementation there can be substantial performance degradation on OSX as great as 200:1 and on iOS as great as 1000:1. For reference a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 AES-128-CBC on 100KB data encrypts at > 400 MB/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I compiled using just "make" command and included libcryptopp.a in my c++ project of my xcode. But it is giving errors ...

As @halfelf said, you need to use LLVM's runtime (`libc++`) because that is what Xcode uses. Depending on the Crypto++ version you have, you may (or may not) be using GNU's runtime (`libstdc++`).

The easiest way to fix this is to checkout Master. Its OK to work from Master because its mostly stable and only suffers an occasional break (most development occurs on a separate branch).

```
$ git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp
Cloning into 'cryptopp'...
remote: Counting objects: 9116, done.
remote: Total 9116 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 9116
Receiving objects: 100% (9116/9116), 8.05 MiB | 6.53 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (6406/6406), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Using Master is required because older versions of Crypto++ did not honor user's `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`. You used to have to edit the makefile to fix it.

Then, perform the following:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++"
$ CXX=clang++ make -j 4
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c cryptlib.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c cpu.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c shacal2.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c md5.cpp
...
```

You have to set Debug/Release build, Symbol level and Optimization level. The makefile will add the rest of the flags.

There's some hand waiving above since it only adds `-stdlib=libc++`. You should use the `CXXFLAGS` that Xcode uses to ensure the most trouble-free link. Using different `CXXFLAGS` has caused a lot of trouble over the years.

---

Crypto++ is fat-binary safe ([unlike cURL and OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25531033/608639)), so you should be able to perform the following. In fact, [our test script tests this class of configurations](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/cryptest.sh#L3393) (Intel and PPC fat binaries, including C++03 through C++17), so it should work out of the box for you:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64"
$ CXX=clang++ make -j 4
$ make -j 4
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c cryptlib.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c cpu.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c shacal2.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c md5.cpp
...
```

Using both architectures will avoid *`Undefined symbols for architecture i386`* and *`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`*.

---

Here are some related Crypto++ wiki pages, but they are for iOS, and not OS X. They mostly apply, but not exactly.

- [IOS (Xcode)](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_(Xcode))
- [IOS (Command Line)](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_(Command_Line))

Here's a wiki article on building the library from the command line. You're actually hitting the pain point discussed under *"Compilers and C++ Runtimes"*, but its not readily apparent:

- [GNUmakefile](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Gnumakefile)

Comment: @user7234 - Open a new question, and provide the details.

Comment: clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -stdlib=libc++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -c camellia.cpp
cpu.cpp:104:4: error: register %rbx is only available in 64-bit mode
                        "pushq %%rbx; cpuid; mov %%ebx, %%edi; popq %%rbx"
<inline asm>:1:8: note: instantiated into assembly here
        pushq %rbx; cpuid; mov %ebx, %edi; popq %rbx
              ^~~~~
cpu.cpp:104:4: error: register %rbx is only available in 64-bit mode
                        "pushq %%rbx; cpuid; mov %%ebx, %%edi; popq %%rbx"

Comment: <inline asm>:1:42: note: instantiated into assembly here
        pushq %rbx; cpuid; mov %ebx, %edi; popq %rbx
                                                ^~~~
2 errors generated.
make: *** [cpu.o] Error 1