# Can't link OpenSSL libraries properly with Mingw on OS X

Tags: c++, openssl, mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

I have some RSA code, however, I can't get it to compile & link properly.

```
build.sh:
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ rsa.cpp -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lcrypto -lssl -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -o main.exe 


result:
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `BIO_new_mem_buf'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `BIO_f_base64'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `BIO_new'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x10b): undefined reference to `BIO_push'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `BIO_read'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `BIO_free_all'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_new'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_assign'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x198): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_create'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `EVP_sha256'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestVerifyInit'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x218): undefined reference to `EVP_DigestVerifyFinal'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x26e): undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x2ac): undefined reference to `BIO_new_mem_buf'
/var/folders/8k/t6rljvrs6l32k49b3834_njr0000gn/T//ccKr56mH.o:rsa.cpp:(.text+0x2da): undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

both libcrypto.a and libssl.a exist in /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib. I'm building on OS X mingw compiler a windows application.

EDIT: `objdump -d /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a > ~/libcrypto.a.txt`

[image]

EDIT2: Tried grouping: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ rsa.cpp -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -Wl,--start-group -lcrypto -lssl -Wl,--end-group -lws2_32 -lwsock32 -liphlpapi -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -o main.exe`, same result

Comment: I had those errors at first when my code needed openSSL 1.0.2 and i had the library for 1.1.0.

Comment: Are those `.a` libs created with the same compiler & configuration as your app? Can you rebuild them?

Comment: why don't you check if these symbols are actually exported by libraries in question using related tools (objdump/etc)?

Comment: also, order of libraries mentioned on cmdline is important -- try things like mentioning `-lcrypto` second time after `-lssl` or [grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651869/gcc-what-are-the-start-group-and-end-group-command-line-options?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: @C.M. check my edit

Comment: try my second suggestion... I bet that symbol is referenced by libssl. Changing the order of these libs may work

Comment: @C.M. tried grouping; tried mentioning -lcrypto after -lssl, still same thing!

Comment: @Ripi2, no, those libraries come with openssl, which I got by `brew install openssl` and `brew upgrade openssl`

Comment: weird... try: moving both of them to the end of cmdline, group them using `--start-grouping`/etc, make sure you are actually using libraries you think you are using (e.g. use `-l:libssl.a` instead of `-lssl`)

Comment: one more thing: rsa.cpp references `EVP_DigestVerifyInit`, but libcrypto.a exports `_EVP_DigestVerifyInit` (note leading underscore). Maybe you forgot some preprocessor definition that changes names of functions you are referencing?

Comment: OSX and Windows are very different targets. I don't think libs obtained with brew can be compatible with Windows. I'd try to compile them on my own, likely with some changes to makefile.

Comment: @C.M. moving it to the end after `-o main.exe` doesn't help. Not familiar with assembler, but I believe it should have been included in openssl headers if it was neccessary. @Ripi2 interesting point, this makes a lot of sense. But then how do I fix it.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40917002/visual-studio-builds-openssl-with-underscore-prefix-to-symbols) out. Looks like calling conventions change exported symbol name. I bet your rsa.cpp observes these functions as __stdcall symbols, while your libraries were built with __cdecl (either explicitly or by default). Or something to that effect... You are likely missing some preprocessor definition in rsa.cpp. Easy way to check -- explicitly declare EVP_PKEY_assign function with various call conventions, use it and see which one will cause linker to stop complaining.

Comment: ... and yes, if your libraries are compiled for another target -- it probably won't work.

Comment: @C.M. could you let me know specifically what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Not really, I'd check symbols exported by a library (`nm -gC <file>`) and compare with symbols linker looks for and try to figure out why they differ and what they should be. In fact, just yesterday I dealt with very similar problem -- one lib exported `std::string` as `std::__cxx11::basic_string`, another as `std::string`. Both libs compiled by the same compiler for the same target, the only difference is that one had `-std=c++11` -- this made it unusable for C++03 application.

Comment: I ended up using windows 10 virtual machine to compile openssl. It worked, but required some .dll (which I don't want to add), so I ended up using crypto++. Thanks anyway

Comment: no probs. Btw, root of my problem was that one lib was compiled under `sudo` -- and ended up picking up older gcc (I have newer version of gcc compiled and installed under /usr/local -- for some reason root user didn't pick it up as default one). So, making sure every build used same compiler fixed everything and removed need of tinkering with compiler flags.

Comment: Why don't you simply build your code on Windows with MinGW ? Compile and check it for Mac native with XCode, if it is working - build it for Windows, this is not a big deal to use VirtualBox or another virtual machine on Mac.

Comment: @Gintas_ Did you try to set `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` Like `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` ?