# File was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked

Tags: c, openssl

I am currently working on a project on encryption and decryption using OpenSSL library, and I'm trying to run a simple encryption. This is my make file:

```
INC=/usr/local/ssl/include/
LIB=/usr/local/ssl/lib/

all:
        gcc -I$(INC) -L$(LIB) -o out encryption.c -lcrypto -ldl
```

Must note I'm not using Xcode or anything like it, just the Terminal. And these are the errors I am receiving:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include/ -L/usr/local/ssl/lib/ -o out ex_1.c -lcrypto -ldl
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/ssl/lib//libcrypto.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /usr/local/ssl/lib//libcrypto.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BIO_dump_fp", referenced from:
      _main in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_ERR_free_strings", referenced from:
      _main in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_ERR_load_crypto_strings", referenced from:
      _main in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_ERR_print_errors_fp", referenced from:
      _handleErrors in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free", referenced from:
      _encrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
      _decrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new", referenced from:
      _encrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
      _decrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_DecryptFinal_ex", referenced from:
      _decrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_DecryptInit_ex", referenced from:
      _decrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_DecryptUpdate", referenced from:
      _decrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_EncryptFinal_ex", referenced from:
      _encrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_EncryptInit_ex", referenced from:
      _encrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_EncryptUpdate", referenced from:
      _encrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_aes_256_cbc", referenced from:
      _encrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
      _decrypt in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_EVP_cleanup", referenced from:
      _main in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf", referenced from:
      _main in ex_1-a0d79f.o
  "_OPENSSL_config", referenced from:
      _main in ex_1-a0d79f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

It works just fine on Ubuntu, on a VirtualBox, while I'm trying to make this work on OS X. I've seen many topics on this but they don't seem to help because they're linked with an IDE or so.

Comment: What version of OS X?

Comment: I am using 10.11.6

Comment: What does `file /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a` tell you?

Comment: `/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: current ar archive random library`

Comment: It looks like your `libcrypto.a` is built for 32-bit compilations and not 64-bit compilations.  You can use `cd /tmp; ar t /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a; ar x /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a objectfile.o; file objectfile.o` where `objectfile.o` is any of the object files listed in the archive.  The output from `file` should tell you whether it is compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit or both.

Comment: `lipo -info libcrpto.a` will tell you if its 32-bit, 64-bit or a fat library. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki and [Build Multiarch OpenSSL on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25530429) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For a quick/dirty test of architectures, try changing your make recipe to include `CFLAGS` of `-arch i386`. If it compiles and links, then `libcrypto.a` is 32-bit. GCC on Darwin [accepts `-arch` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Darwin-Options.html) (but you are probably using Clang).

Comment: Please check using nm or strings on the library file if the symbols are present or not. Also, check compatibility. Libraries in OS X are generally compiled using clang. May be some other mismatch.