# Linker and compiler errors with openssl

Tags: c, macos, openssl, linker-errors

I am trying to build openssl from the github release https://github.com/openssl/openssl/archive/OpenSSL-fips-2_0_13.tar.gz and trying to compile it manually.  I am trying to compile this on a Mac OSX version 10.11.5, this is the series of steps I have taken

```
./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc
make
```

But I get this error

```
bsaes-x86_64.s:580:1: error: invalid symbol redefinition
_bsaes_enc_key_convert:
```

When I compile normally according to the `INSTALL` file, I get en error in the link step, presumably because the archive file was built for a 32 bit system.  This is the warning I get when running `./config`

```
WARNING! If you wish to build 64-bit library, then you have to
         invoke './Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc' *manually*.
         You have about 5 seconds to press Ctrl-C to abort.
```

And then the corresponding error when linking with the archive from the `./config && make` step is this

```
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file openssl/lib/libssl.a, file was
built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): 
openssl/lib/libssl.aignoring file openssl/lib/libcrypto.a, file was built 
for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): 
openssl/lib/libcrypto.a
```

*Note*  I am building this for a C++ project using a C compiler to compile the C code and using a c++ compiler (or `ld` since both compilers use the same linker?) to link code (not sure if that makes a difference)

Could someone tell me how to build and link with openssl correctly?

Comment: You ***cannot*** build OpenSSL library with a C++ compiler. You must use a C compiler. Later, you ***can*** compile a user program with a C++ compiler. You can also perform `KERNEL_BITS=64 ./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 ...`. A related question is [Build Multiarch OpenSSL on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25530429) on Stack Overflow. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: @jww I was wrong in saying i was using a C++ compiler, I was compiling the code using a C compiler and then linking with a C++ compiler.  I will correct the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `no-asm` option during `./configure`:

```
$ make clean
$ ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc no-asm
$ make test
$ make 
....
```

Elliptic curve routines seem to be broken in this version, so maybe file a bug report about that, otherwise it should compile/build without issue.