# g++ Linker command fails when trying to compile with openssl function is used

Tags: c++, openssl, g++, ld, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to use the OpenSSL `EVP.h` in a C++ file. Each time I try to compile, however, I get an error about linking, for example:

```
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I've tried the following solutions:

- [Linker and compiler errors with openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41405707/)
- I’ve tried reinstalling with openssl with brew
- Tried both:

  - -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include
  - -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include
- Tried adding on “-libssl -libcrypto” on the end, only for it to say “ld: library not found for -libssl”
- Doing `ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/ | grep “ssl”` returns only libboringssl.tbd
- Doing `find /usr/local/opt/openssl@3/ | grep “libssl”` returns /lib/libssl.a among other files
- If I attach “-arch x86_64” to my compile command, it says: `ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/' for architecture x86_64`

My code is:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

#define kek 20
#define key_len 32
#define iteration 1

unsigned char salt[] = {'s', 'a', 'l', 't'};
char password[] = "test";

unsigned char *out;

size_t i;

out = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * kek);

if( PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1(password, strlen(password), salt, sizeof(salt), iteration, kek, out) != 0 )
{
    cout << out;
}

free(out);

return 0;
}
```

The command I'm using to compile is: `g++ -I/usr/local/opt/openssl\@3/include -Wl,/usr/local/opt/openssl\@3/lib/ -arch x86_64 test.cpp`

My macOS version is Big Sur 11.2.

Comment: You are providing the wrong arguments to `g++`. Instead of the `-Wl` option, you should provide a `-L` option with the `/usr/local/opt/openssl\@3/lib/` directory path as argument and afterwards you should add `-l` options _after_ `test.cpp` matching the library you want to link without the `lib` prefix and `.a`/`.so` suffix, e.g. `-lssl -lcrypto`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much. For future peoples, this is the command that ended up working for me: `g++ -I/usr/local/opt/openssl\@3/include -arch x86_64 -L/usr/local/opt/openssl\@3/lib/ test.cpp -lssl -lcrypto`.
Would you like to add that as an answer so I can mark it as correct @user17732522 ?