# Libssh2-iOS, CocoaPod linker error

Tags: ios, openssl, cocoapods, libssh2

I tried Cocoapod *Libssh2-iOS 1.6.0*, but got a compile error. It's Xcode 8.2.1. The build of the included *openssl* stopped with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSLDIR="/var/folders/d4/mby6kr4j6y389b213bdyq31w0000gn/T/Libssh2/iPhoneSimulator10.2-i386" -DENGINESDIR="/usr/local/lib/engines-1.1" -Wall -O3 -pthread -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,-soname=libcrypto.so.1.1 -o ./libcrypto.so.1.1 -Wl,--whole-archive,--version-script=crypto.map ./libcrypto.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [link_shlib.linux-shared] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libcrypto.so] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is this Cocoapod still valid? I am bit confused, the offered project-links are dead. Shall I use the pod *libssh2* instead?
Is there a *libssh* that uses the SSL implementation of the security.framework?

Comment: `-Bsymbolic` is for shared objects/dynamic libraries. My gut feeling is OpenSSL and SSH should be built with `no-shared` because many iOS versions don't allow dylib's. Would you happen to know why CocoaPods is trying to build an OpenSSL shared object for iOS? Something else that looks unusual is the lack of an `-arch` option to the tools.

Comment: `make[2]` targets `link_shlib.linux-shared` which is wrong for iOS, obviously. This pod seems not to be maintained anymore, but I do not know whom to ask...

Comment: Maybe you can forgo CocoaPods, and have a try with [Compilation and Installation | iOS](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#iOS) from the OpenSSL wiki. If you want to do the multiarch thing for OpenSSL, then see [Build Multiarch OpenSSL on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25530429/608639). I don't really know SSH build procedures that well, so I can't comment.