# linker error while linking to arm64 library on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, arm64

I'm trying to build my project for arm64. This project requires an arm64 libcrypto.a. I'd like to know if I'm missing any settings. Thanks in advance...

The error I see is:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Amy/Desktop/swift_proj/swift_proj/include/libcrypto.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/Amy/Desktop/swift_proj/swift_proj/include/libcrypto.a
```

My project settings are shown below:

```
Architectures: arm64
Base SDK: Latest iOS(iOS 11.4)
Build Active Architecture Only: No
Supported Platforms: iOS
Valid Architectures: arm64
```

I've updated "RequiredDeviceCapabilities" in info.plist to arm64.

I've checked the type of library I'm trying to link with:

```
[Amys-MacBook-Air:include$ lipo -info libcrypto.a 
input file libcrypto.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libcrypto.a is architecture: arm64
```

I fail to understand why the error says the project is being built for x86_64.

Comment: What version of xcode are you using ?

Comment: @Hary: I'm using Xcode 9.4.1 on Mac High Sierra(10.13.6).

Comment: Are you trying to build for a simulator target?

Comment: @pckill : No I'm trying to build for an actual iphone.
Do I need to have a phone connected even to build the project successfully?

Comment: No, but you should select the correct device for Xcode to build for the correct architecture. Use the `Generic iOS Device` if your phone is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like OpenSSL has some issues with multi-arch builds that you need to address for it to work, the answer here [Build Multiarch OpenSSL on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530429/build-multiarch-openssl-on-os-x/25531033) should help.

Essentially, you'll have to replace a couple of the OpenSSL header files that include the architecture-specific header using `#ifdef` to check the system architecture at compile time. Do this after building OpenSSL from source for each target that you want. Then you'll be able to use the `lipo` tools to combine each target's static library build for OpenSSL into one static library, then use that.