# Python crashing on macOS ARM M1

Tags: python, openssl, apple-m1, libcrypto, macos-ventura

I recently installed Python 3.10.9 using Brew on my ARM mac (macOS 13.1 Ventura) but when running any of my Python script with PyCharm (native for ARM using a system env with Python 3.10.9 /usr/local/bin/python3), Python crashes and returns one of the 2 error reports, as shown below:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Python [78382]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            org.python.python
Version:               3.10.9 (3.10.9)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        pycharm [77323]
Responsible:           pycharm [77323]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-01-02 19:22:46.8969 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 13.1 (22C65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        90007ABA-5D79-9CD1-C540-78C58ED447AC

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C0F3DA32-9A4C-40DA-B838-0C43B7D63AA1

Time Awake Since Boot: 22000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       59 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000001e
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000001e

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [78382]
```

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Python [86657]
Path:                  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            org.python.python
Version:               3.10.9 (3.10.9)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        pycharm [84646]
Responsible:           pycharm [84646]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-01-02 22:59:59.8243 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 13.1 (22C65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        90007ABA-5D79-9CD1-C540-78C58ED447AC

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C7252D6D-6A22-475B-BEB4-81B2B1C35C73

Time Awake Since Boot: 30000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1526 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001a3b8e810

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [86657]
```

I saw that sometimes Python's installation using Brew can sometimes results in weird issues, therefore I tried to uninstall and reinstall using Python installer from Python.org. Didn't change a thing.

Also uninstall/reinstall openssl, tried with version 1.0.2t, 1.1.1s and 3.0.7. Tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450267/18937449), which worked on my intel mac. Yet, this failed to solve the matter here.

I then tried to manually link openssl. Didn't solve my issue.

And at last, I tried using `lido` to combine binaries, both the intel and ARM versions, but this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69029436) didn't work, both command `cp -r openssl-1.1.1s openssl-1.1.1s-arm64` and `cp -r openssl-1.1.1s openssl-1.1.1s-x86_x64` returned `cp: openssl-1.1.1s: No such file or directory`, even when openssl@1.1 (version 1.1.1s) is installed using Brew.

So far none of those solutions worked for me.